# Puppet ERB templates: How to inject variable into statement

Tags: ruby, puppet

I'd like to make some modifications on variable in erb templates:
e.g. decode base64 and split string

It tried

```
<%= Base64.decode64(@my_variable).rpartition(':').last %>
```

and

```
<%= Base64.decode64(<%= @my_variable %>).rpartition(':').last %>
```

and via scope

```
<%= Base64.decode64(scope['my_class::my_variable']).rpartition(':').last %>
```

but it is nil.

```
 Filepath: /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/base64.rb
  Line: 58
  Detail: undefined method `unpack' for nil:NilClass
```

puppet version 3.8.2

Comment: Added to question

Comment: I don't know puppet very well but your first version is valid syntax, it's whoever is rendering the ERB template that binds the variable: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_template_erb.html#accessing-puppet-variables

Comment: Thanks. Will dig into puppet template loading mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

The first example that you tried is the correct ERB notation.

That error would be occurring because you passed the nil object to `Base64.decode64()`:

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'base64'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> Base64.decode64(nil).rpartition(':').last
NoMethodError: undefined method `unpack' for nil:NilClass
from /Users/alexharvey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/base64.rb:58:in `decode64'
```

(Admittedly, I don't have your Ruby 1.9.1 and I wasn't able to easily install it, but it's unlikely this changed.)

That means that `@my_variable` is set to `nil`, and that would happen if you failed to actually set the Puppet variable `$my_variable` in your manifest.

So you would need to call the template with a block something like this:

```
  $my_variable = 'foo'
  file { '/tmp/foo':
    ensure  => file,
    content => template('test/mytemplate.erb')
  }
```